# how to preview but not edit an image chosen with UIImagePickerController in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Was hoping somebody can help me with this.  I am using an imagePicker to select an image from my photo library in an iOS chat app.

I want the behaviour of selecting the image to mimic that of iMessage.  The specific problem I am having is seeing a preview of the selected image.  I want to see this preview and have the option to choose or cancel, but NOT to edit.

If I set imagePicker.allowsEditing = True, the preview of the selected image is shown, however I can scroll and zoom it.  I want the image to just display statically.

If I set the imagePicker.allowsEditing = False, once the image is chosen from the library the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is called without the image being previewed.  If I then add a segue in this method and set up my own view, there is no way to go back to the library as it is dismissed already.

Basically I just want to mimic the iMessage way of picking an image from my library and was hoping to do it without using a custom imagePicker

Thank you

Comment: Hi, I am having your same trouble now (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787959/swift-how-to-prevent-uiimagepicker-method-takepicture-from-calling-didfinishp). Have you found a solution? Even if I have set `self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true` nothing happens when I hit the "shot photo" button...

Comment: hi.  i ended up creating my own collectionView to view my photos.  it's slightly more work but gives you much more control over your work.  i just use the image picker for the camera.